# Elementary OS won't boot up after installing

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, error

I installed Elementary OS on my HP Pavillon 15 with i7-1165G7 and Nvidia MX450 and it won't boot up after installation. I get an error on the black screen saying something like `rtw_pci: failed to wait firmware completion.`.

If I try to boot in recovery mode it works (pretty bad though, with no Wi-Fi, no touchpad). So in recovery mode I tried do install all the software updates from the App Center. Nothing changed.

Then I tried to install the nvidia driver from the App Center and after that it won't boot even in recovery mode showing black screen and ticking cursor.

I tried to install several times, with and without internet connection.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a graphics card problem, when installing Elementary OS did you select to install proprietary drivers?

When you use Nvidia graphics it is advised to do so, to install such drivers during the installation just select the box that says

> Install third-party software for graphics and WI-FI hardware and additional media formats